# Error when importing SciPy within an application

Tags: python, scipy, raspberry-pi

I have a python application running on the latest Raspberry Pi OS (Debian version 11 (bullseye)) and I am getting an error when importing SciPy. The specific error is:

```
from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know why this error is being thrown or how to fix it? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling SciPy but that doesn't help. I am also running in a python `venv` with python 3.9 and SciPy version 1.8.1 in case that makes a difference.

Comment: From the message (I have no direct knowledge of this package), it seems likely you're missing an OS package that the python package relies on. From a quick google of `libf77blas.so.3` it appears you might need to `apt-get install libatlas3-base` (via https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libf77blas.so.3)

Comment: Awesome, looks like that was the problem, thanks! I had installed `libblas3` instead, which didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by installing `libatlas3-base` with `apt-get install libatlas3-base` which contains `libf77blas.so.3`.